# How i can include label code in menu

Tags: html, blogger

when i include this label url http://dewdropzone.blogspot.com/search/label/English%20Movie?&max-results=24 in this menu code

```
<li><a href='http://dewdropzone.blogspot.com/search/label/English%20Movie?&max-results=24'>English</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then show this error message,  "Error parsing XML, line 476, column 87: The reference to entity "max-results" must end with the ';' delimiter."
if i delete max-results=24 from this url then when i go menu category then show 20 post not 24 post . how i include this blogger url with max-results=24 in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `&` symbol with `?&amp;` without and it works:

```
<li><a href='http://koran-madura.blogspot.com/search?q=sumenep?&amp;max-results=10?&amp;by-date=true'>Sumenep</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better you shorten the url using bit.ly or goo.gl or any other services then use that short url. I hope that will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use (/search/label/test?&max-results=7) for exemple :

```
<a href='/search/label/test?&amp;max-results=7' itemprop='url' title='test'></a>
```